# Using a plugin component from shell class in cakephp 2.0.2

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I would like to make use of a plugin component from my shell class. I am trying to use:

```
App::import('Component', 'Myplugin.Mycomponent');
$this->Mycomponent =& new MycomponentComponent();
```

Unfortunately the above seems to fail.

And I get an error message saying that the Component class could not be found.

Any suggestion how I should tackle this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should always take a look at the test cases first! this way you would have found out that they are manually included this way:

```
App::uses('ComponentCollection', 'Controller');
App::uses('AppleComponent', 'Myplugin.Controller/Component');
```

and

```
$Collection = new ComponentCollection();
$Apple = new AppleComponent($Collection);
```

sidenote:
if you need to use a component somewhere else than a controller than you are doing sth wrong!
you should extract the functionality into a model or lib and call it from both the component and the shell

Comment: thanks for you help mark. However I am unsure about the second line. I did something like this: App::uses('PokerAliasesWebService', 'Pluginname.Controller/Component'); Could you help me undestand? Thank you.

Comment: sry, I corrected my statement from above: it is `App::uses('PokerAliasesWebServiceComponent', ...)`

Comment: ok so my code currently looks like this: 
`App::uses('Component', 'Controller');
App::uses('PokerAliasesWebServiceComponent', 'Pluginname.Controller/Component');
$Collection = new ComponentCollection();
$this->PokerAliasesWebService = new PokerAliasesWebServiceComponent($Collection);` but I get an error saying the ComponentCollection class could not be found.

Comment: you do realize that `Pluginname` should be your plugin name, right? I edited my post accordingly.

Comment: Hi mark, yes I tried that too but I still get  the ComponentCollection class not found error.

Comment: again, looking at the test cases helps: you will probably also need `App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');`

Comment: I edited my answer to show how component collection can be added manually

Comment: Alright that works :) ... Thanks for your help. Where do I find these test cases you mention?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is hella old, but I just ran into this while working on a legacy CakePHP 2 application.

In your controller:

```
public $components = array(
    'Myplugin.Mycomponent',
);
```

You can then access the component via:

```
$this->Mycomponent->mymethod();
```

[Source](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/plugins/how-to-create-plugins.html#components-helpers-and-behaviors)