# Using a Plugin in Cakephp Shell

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I am writing a shell that will send emails to users who post a message on our website.  The emailing is done via Mandrill and comes by way of a plugin.

Here's the path:

/app/Plugin/mandrill/Controller/Component/MandrillComponent.php

Following this answered SO post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10880694/using-a-plugin-component-from-shell-class-in-cakephp-2-0-2), I have the following:

```
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');
App::uses('ComponentCollection', 'Controller');
App::uses('MandrillComponent', 'mandrill.Controller/Component');`

$Collection = new ComponentCollection();
$Mandrill = new MandrillComponent($Collection);
```

I run the shell via Console/cake NotifyMailer, but get the error: **Plugin mandrill could not be found.**

I've been struggling with this for a while so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you loaded your plugin in your Config/bootstrap.php?

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins.html

```
CakePlugin::loadAll(); // Loads all plugins at once
CakePlugin::load('Mandrill'); //Loads a single plugin
```

I think by cakephp 2.x convention all your plugins should start with a capital letter ie. Mandrill instead of mandrill